# Simple graphical editor on Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, mobile

I want to create a simple graphical editor for Windows Phone 7. User will choose an instrument and draw smth.
To drawing i want to use [WriteableBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap%28VS.95%29.aspx), because per-pixel drawing needed sometimes.
Is that a good idea or any best way exists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

its good idea becouse of performance loss,and good for GC,when creating the WriteableBitmap, the application must define the image properties such as the
width, height, and pixel format. This allows the WriteableBitmap object to allocate the memory once and just update pixel data as needed.

Comment: @DenisIonov Im using it in my Kinect application when processing frames cheers ;)